# Identity for a scalar quintuple product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I find myself needing to cross two pairs of vectors, and cross that result (so a normal of normals) and check whether each of two of the original points are on different sides of the plane it defines:

$$
(A\times B)\times (C\times D) \cdot A \lt 0 \\
(A\times B)\times (C\times D) \cdot B \gt 0
$$

Since the ultimate result is a scalar, It'd be great if I could eliminate the cross products altogether (similar to how [Lagrange's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) does for the triple product).

Does anyone know of a similar identity for a scalar quintuple product?